# Compiling with .lst file

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I am trying to install the MIRACL library for my crypto system. While I was configuring the library, it gave me "miracle.lst" that contains list of files I need to compile. I was just wondering is there any way me to compile all files inside of .lst file once? I don't think it is an assembly file because it only contains names. I saw this link but it is nothing related with my situation.
[List File In C (.LST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131228/list-file-in-c-lst)

Inside of miracl.lst

mrcore.c

mrarth0.c

mrarth1.c

mrarth2.c

...

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
gcc -I./include -c -O2 source/mr*.c
```

Comment: that may accidentially include other files matching the wildcard